# How is the sortedArrayUsingComparator method implemented?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, sorting, compare

I was trying to rewrite the official `sortedArrayUsingComparator:` method in Objective-C. How can I do this?

In the `NSArray` class, how are the elements actually stored in the array?
What is the type (in the code: `type?`) in the for-loop? Generics do not seem to exist in Objective-C. How does the `compare:` method work?

```
- (NSArray *)recentQuestions {
    return [questions sortedArrayUsingComparator: ^(id obj1, id obj2) {
        Question *q1 = (Question *)obj1; 
        Question *q2 = (Question *)obj2; 
        return [q2.date compare: q1.date];
}]; }

//class NSArray

//? NSArray* selfArray = @[];
-(...) sortedArrayUsingComparator : (void (^)(id obj1, id obj2) ) blockName{
    for ( int i=0; i<selfArray.count-1; i++){ 
        for ( int j=i+1; j<selfArray.count; j++){ 
            type? *bigger = blockName(selfArray[i], selfArray[j]);          
            //move items if j>i
            if (bigger isEqual:selfArray[j]) {
                int tempValue = newArray[i];
                newArray[i] = newArray[j];
                newArray[j] = tempValue;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The method already exists and it looks like you know how to invoke it.. I'm not sure what you're asking here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll attempt to answer the questions you have asked.

---

**In the NSArray class, how are actually store the elements added to the array?**

I think you're asking how to add new elements or modify the order of elements within an `NSArray`. This is not possible. You should be using an `NSMutableArray` if you need to mutate the contents of the array. With an `NSMutableArray`, the following is possible:

```
id tempValue = newArray[i];
newArray[i] = newArray[j];
newArray[j] = tempValue;
```

---

**What is the type (in the code: `type?`) in the for-loop? `Generics` does not seem to exist in objective-c.**

The type that you should expect there is whatever return type you have from your block. In your case, the block you have specified has a `void` return type, meaning that you really shouldn't be trying to assign a variable from its result. Below, you will see the return type should be listed as `NSComparisonResult`.

In my answer to the first question, you may have noticed how a generic pointer is treated in objective-c: `id`. Every non-primitive object can be held in an `id` variable.

---

**How does the compare method work?**

```
-(...) sortedArrayUsingComparator : (void (^)(id obj1, id obj2) ) blockName{
```

You should specify a return type for `sortedArrayUsingComparator`. I suggest `NSArray`. Your block should also have a return type of `NSComparisonResult`.

```
-(NSArray *) sortedArrayUsingComparator : (NSComparisonResult (^)(id obj1, id obj2) ) blockName{
```

Now when you invoke the block, you'll get a value representing the result of comparing two objects. This will be one of `NSOrderedSame`, `NSOrderedDescending`, or `NSOrderedAscending`.

---

I'm unclear what your `selfArray` and `newArray` values are intended to be here. It looks like you're comparing values within `selfArray`, but then changing the order of `newArray` based on that comparison. It didn't sound like you were asking about the algorithm used to sort things, so I'll just leave that alone.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I was wondering how the official method was written. For 1/ I know about mutableArray, I was actually wondering how NSArray store its elements, (or MutableArray, but I guess an array can create and return a mutableArray in one of its functions?). So selfArray might be wrong, it is just that I don't know what to use in a for-loop if I had to rewrite the NSArray class, and use the elements inside of the array to sort them.

Answer (score 2):

A class can use itself as soon as it is defined. There-for it can be used inside it.

It is possible that NSArray uses NSMutableArray in its implementation, but this would be awkward as NSArray is a superclass of NSMutableArray and it is considered bad design if a superclass depends on knowledge subclasses.

#### but…

Actually we are never dealing with NSArrays, nor with NSMutableArrays, which are [class clusters](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/ClassCluster.html) that creates, when instantiated, yet other subclasses as __NSArrayI (immutable) and __NSArrayM (mutable). it is absolutely fine if both of them knows the public NSMutableArray interface.

There-for probably the method just double-loops (more-likely some better sorting algorithm. or even several for different memory situations) over the array and fill a NSMutableArray before a immutable copy is returned.

---

A basic implementation with runtime complexity O(*n*<sup>2</sup>) and memory usage of O(1) could look like this:

```
@interface NSArray (Comparator)
-(NSArray *)vs_sortedArrayUsingComparator:(NSComparisonResult(^)(id obj1, id obj2))comparator;
@end

@implementation NSArray (Comparator)

-(NSArray *)vs_sortedArrayUsingComparator:(NSComparisonResult(^)(id obj1, id obj2))comparator
{
    NSMutableArray *array = [self mutableCopy];
    if ([array count] > 1) {
        for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < [array count] - 1; ++i) {
            for (NSUInteger j  = i; j < [array count]; ++j) {
                if (comparator(array[i], array[j]) == NSOrderedDescending) {
                    [array exchangeObjectAtIndex:i withObjectAtIndex:j];
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return [array copy];
}
@end
```

Usage:

```
NSArray *array = @[@4, @9, @2, @1, @7];

array = [array vs_sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(id obj1, id obj2) {
    return  [obj1 compare:obj2];
}];
```

Results in

```
(
    1,
    2,
    4,
    7,
    9
)
```

---

A faster implementation with runtime complexity O(*n* log *n*) , though requires more memory (average: O(log(*n*))) would be quicksort
 where comparison between object and pivot element is performed by the comparator block:

```
@interface NSArray (Comparator)
-(NSArray *)vs_sortedArrayUsingComparator:(NSComparisonResult(^)(id obj1, id obj2))comparator;
@end

@implementation NSArray (Comparator)
-(NSArray *) quicksortUsingComparator:(NSComparisonResult(^)(id obj1, id obj2))comparator
{
    NSArray *array = [self copy];

    if ([array count]<2) return [array copy];

    id pivot = [array randomElement];
    NSMutableArray *array2= [NSMutableArray array];

    array = [array arrayByPerformingBlock:^id  (id element) { return element;}
                      ifElementPassesTest:^BOOL(id element) { return comparator(element, pivot) == NSOrderedAscending;}
                         elsePerformBlock:^    (id element) { if (element!=pivot) [array2 addObject:element];}
            ];
    return [[[array quicksortUsingComparator:comparator]
                                    arrayByAddingObject:pivot]
                                        arrayByAddingObjectsFromArray:[array2 quicksortUsingComparator:comparator]];
}

-(NSArray *)vs_sortedArrayUsingComparator:(NSComparisonResult(^)(id obj1, id obj2))comparator
{
    return [self quicksortUsingComparator:comparator];
}
@end
```

---

As in both implementation only `vs_sortedArrayUsingComparator:` is presented to the public, it is easy to imagine that behind the scene different algorithms might be used under different circumstances.  Quicksort is a very fast one but for very big list it might create an stack overflow. In such a case it could be better to switch to another algorithm that might be slower but implements in-place sorting.

---

The full implementation of the Quicksort example can be found here: http://vikingosegundo.github.io/2015/02/05/implement-comparator/

Including

```
- (NSArray *)arrayByPerformingBlock:(id   (^)(id element))performBlock 
                ifElementPassesTest:(BOOL (^)(id element))testBlock
                   elsePerformBlock:(void (^)(id element))elseBlock;
```

and

```
-(id)randomElement;
```

---

> What is the type (in the code: type?) i

`id`, which translates to «a pointer to any object». You can abbreviate it to «any object», as all objects in Objective-C are only accessible through pointers.

Comment: A better algorithm than quicksort is the iterative Merge sort.

Comment: better in what regard? also: who cares? these are demonstration codes.